# limpiar y validar campos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buenas noches
no soy muy avanzado programando pero tengo un formulario con varios campos, lo que necesito es validar que solo se ingresen números o letras según el campo, pero que limpie el campo donde se fallo después de validar.

los campos estan asi:

```
 <input class="cajas" type="text" name="username" maxlength="10"
               onblur="return validanumero(this.value)" required title="Solo 
 numeros">
```

y la validación la realizo por medio de una función:

```
function validanumero(numero){
if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(numero)){
    alert("Ingrese solo numeros");        
}
}
```

el form tiene varios campos y están en archivos php diferentes.

Agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas complicarte con librerías para estas validaciones tan sencillas, lo único que debes hacer es enviar a tus funciones de validación el elemento como tal (`this`) luego en la función podrás manipular su `value` y hacer tu lógica sin ningún problema.

Como dato adicional te aconsejaría mejor utilizar el evento `onchange` que es el evento que se dispara cuando se detecta un cambio en el valor del `input`.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcional

```js
function validanumero(elemento){
  if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(elemento.value)){
      alert("Ingrese solo numeros");
      elemento.value = '';
  }
}

function validatexto(elemento){
  if (!/^([a-zA-Zá-ú])*$/.test(elemento.value)){
      alert("Ingrese solo numeros");
      elemento.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Solo números:</label>
<input class="cajas" type="text" name="username" maxlength="10" onchange="return validanumero(this)" required title="Solo 
 numeros">
 
 <br><br>
 
 <label>Solo letras:</label>
 <input class="cajas" type="text" name="username" maxlength="10" onchange="return validatexto(this)" required title="Solo 
 numeros">
```

Comment: perfecto.... muchas gracias funciono correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Para esa funcionalidad y si eres nuevo puedes usar una librería muy buena [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) con ella puedes validar y hacer mascaras para que no se pueda ingresar en este caso solo números o lo contrario solo letras hasta podemos validar el ingreso de caracteres especiales.

Para el ejemplo en la libreria le pasamos dentro de `pattern` una **Expresion Regular** con lo que necesitas te dejo ejemplo de solo `numero` y `letras`.

**Ejemplo Funcional**

```js
$("#inputSoloNumeros").mask('ZZ',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[0-9\s]/, recursive: true}}});

$("#inputSoloLetras").mask('ZZ',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[áéíóúñüàèa-zA-Z\s]/, recursive: true}}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.13/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<label for="">Solo Numeros</label>
  <input id="inputSoloNumeros" type="text" name="" value="">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="">Solo Letras</label>
  <input id="inputSoloLetras" type="text" name="" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un `id` al `input` en el html para así poder manejarlo y manipularlo desde JavaScript.

Después de asignarle un `id`, guardas en una variable el input, con el método `getElementById()`, que es básico para el manejo del `DOM`, en el cual pasas el `id` que has asignado en el html. De esta manera, ya puedes manejar el input desde JavaScript con diferentes métodos y funciones.

Por último, los objetos de tipo `input` tiene la propiedad `value` que representa su valor. Para limpiar el campo puedes pasarle un valor vacío, y el texto del `input` se borrará. La sintaxis sería `elementoInput.value = ''`

Te dejo algunos enlaces para que puedas investigar más sobre estos temas;

[Introducción a la manipulación del DOM](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/dom/)

[getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

[Elemento input y atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input)

Y el código que resolvería tu problema, tal y como lo he comentado anteriormente, es el siguiente;

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input_js');

function validanumero(numero){
  if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(numero)){
    alert("Ingrese solo numeros");
    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
 <input id="input_js" class="cajas" type="text" name="username" maxlength="10"
               onblur="return validanumero(this.value)" required title="Solo 
 numeros">
```